# Find the regions that dilate and contract

Tags: calculus, complex-analysis

*Find the regions of the complex plane that dilate and contract for* $$f(z)=\frac{z+i}{iz+3}$$

So we know that when $|f'(z)| < 1$ we have contraction and when it's $>1$ we have dilatation.

I have computed $f'(z)=\frac{4}{(iz+3)^2}$.
Now I need to compute the modulus of $f'(z)$ so I can make it equal to $1$.
$$|f'(z)|=\frac{|4|}{|iz+3|^2}$$

$|iz+3|^2=4$ is the equation I have to solve in order to find these regions in the complex plane that neither dilate nor contract, is that right? If so I am quite stuck at computing the modulus.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You can write $f$, which is in the form of $\frac{g(z)}{h(z)}$ in the form $\frac{g(z)\overline{h(z)}}{h(z)\overline{h(z)}}$. In the divisor you'll have a real number, making your life a little easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hint: Your argument is fine. For the last part, write $iz+3=i(x+iy)+3=ix + (3-y)$ and calculate the (square of the) modulus. You should come up with a circle.